# Make react-native run-android command to not download files when compile project

Tags: react-native

I was trying to compile a react-native app for android in Linux platform.

But when I run the command "react-native run-android", I got the following error

```
Scanning folders for symlinks in /opt/react/App5/node_modules (8ms)
JS server already running.
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug)...
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip

Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:673)
    at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:173)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.(HttpsClient.java:264)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1156)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1050)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1564)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:263)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:58)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:44)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:59)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:46)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:46)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:126)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
```

I am behind a proxy server that don't allow me to download the file
https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip,

I download the file using another computer. Is it possible to setup "react-native run-android" command to not download the file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a way to fix the problem:

I find the file gradle-wrapper.properties inside the folder "gradle/wrapper" and change the content of the distributionUrl to

distributionUrl=file:/tmp/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip

It works now, it is not necessary to download the file anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and the work around worked, but then I ran into other issues that required me to fix it. It turns out that an old proxy was causing issues; gradle had the proxy in the default user profile.

Locate Global Gradle Configuration

For me:

```
%USERPROFILE%\.gradle\gradle.properties
```

There were only four entries in my file; all proxy related so I removed them and everything worked.